# How to access the HttpServletRequest in the CXF Simple Frontend Service Class

Tags: cxf, frontend

All

I have created a simple service using CXF Simple Frontend by referring to official document at
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/simple-frontend.html

I'm just wondering how I can access the HttpServletRequest in the method  of service implementation class HelloWorldImpl in the example of the above link.

Any help would be appreciated.

Best Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess, you can try something like:

```
PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage().get("...");
```

To find the exact key cotaining the request use - `PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage().keySet();`. It should contain someting like Http Request.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: I tried the code below, it seems work. 
PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage().get("HTTP.REQUEST")

Answer (score 6):

You can use: `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext` class to retrieve the `HttpServletRequest`. In your implementation add:

```
@Context 
private MessageContext context;

HttpServletRequest request = context.getHttpServletRequest();
```

And you will get the request.

Comment: This works unless your service bean is a singleton which is the default. In that case you need the context injected into the service method like so: `foo(@Context MessageContext context, ...)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

private HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
    HttpServletRequest req;
    if (mc != null) {
        req = (HttpServletRequest) mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
    } else {
        req = request;
    }
    return req;
}
```